# CSS tricks or javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to add a function to this HTML and CSS code.

HTML

```
<div class="switch">
  <input name="sincro" type="radio" checked="checked">
  <label>O</label>
  <input name="sincro" type="radio">
  <label>I</label>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.switch {position:relative; overflow:hidden; border:1px gray solid; background-color:white; }
.switch label {position:relative; z-index:2; float:left; width:50%; height:100%; -webkit-transition:all 0.1s ease-out; -moz-transition:all 0.1s ease-out; transition:all 0.1s ease-out; background-color:gray; }
.switch input {position:absolute; z-index:3; opacity:0; width:100%; height:100%; -moz-appearance:none; }
.switch input:hover, div.switch input:focus {cursor:pointer; }
.switch input:checked {display:none; }
.switch input {display:block; }
.switch input:first-of-type + label {left:-50%; }
.switch input:first-of-type:checked + label {left:0%; }
.switch input:last-of-type + label {right:-50%; left:auto; background-color:green; }
.switch input:last-of-type:checked + label {right:0%; left:auto; }
```

In practice, I would keep graphically the function that simulates the ON and OFF of the button and implementing the functionality to show and hide one DIV with a specific ID="".

I tried with only CSS or with javascript but it doesen't work completely because if works the simulation of the botton the hide and show doesn't work...Help please!!!

Comment: Will you put your code on fiddle??

Comment: More importantly, will you put the relevant parts of your code in your question?

Comment: Your question title is incomplete. CSS or JS to do what?

Comment: Did you try jquery? Regarding showing, hiding a div you could take a look at http://api.jquery.com/show/ or http://api.jquery.com/hide/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Fwxe6/

Answer (score 1):

Sounds to me like you want to show or hide a div based on whether a radio option is selected.  I put together the following fiddle that toggles the display of a div based on a button:

http://jsfiddle.net/pYVys/

It uses the Bootstrap CSS library for styling and jQuery for the logic.  All this does is toggle the `btn-info` CSS class on the button to change its color and the `hidden` class on a div to show/hide it based on the button clicks.

The HTML is very simple:

```
<button id="toggle-button" class="btn">Toggle</button>
<div id="hidden-div" class="hidden">I am in the div</div>
```

And the JavaScript is minimal:

```
$('#toggle-button').click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('btn-info');
    $('#hidden-div').toggleClass('hidden');
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but it is not what I want. I tried to incorporate your suggestion to my code but it does not work because i don't want to use the tag button, the DIV does not appear. http://jsfiddle.net/Fwxe6/1/

Comment: Nice work.  I my JavaScript to work with your fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/Fwxe6/5/.  Also, check out http://www.bootstrap-switch.org/, makes the switch super pretty.  Fiddle using it here: http://jsfiddle.net/Fwxe6/7/